# Generate more nodes for routing

Tags: qgis, postgis, pgrouting

The following picture shows my routing database all set for querying loaded to QGIS. Red line is the road I want to select route from, yellow points are the vertices generated after running pgr_createTopology() and the violet points are bus stops. As per the tutorial [here](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/geoserver.html), everything works fine using qgis db manager.

[image]

I want to show route from one bus stops to another using pgRouting. Since there are more bus stops than the automatic generated vertices, one vertices is selected for multiple bus stops.Is this is because of something wrong in my road shapefile or anything else? is there anything wrong with the procedure i am following ?

[image]